# How to get a list of items from nested lists in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

```yaml
- set_fact:
    cli_list:
      - - first list
      - - second list 
      - - third list
```

I'm expecting the output in this format, how to do it in ansible?

```yaml
cli_list:
  - first list
  - second list
  - third list
```

Comment: `cli_list | flatten`

Comment: Thank you it was simple, I thought I should join it and do something more.. appreciate for the help